# Matrix equation solving guidelines

Tags: linear-algebra

Does anyone how to solve this matrix equation?
$$ PXQ^T+P^TXQ=A$$
where all matrices are real and square. Can you provide me with some guidelines?
Thanx

Answer (score 2):

Use [vectorization operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_%28mathematics%29)  $\mathrm{vec}(\cdot)$ to convert your matrix equation into linear equation form.

Note that
$\mathrm{vec}(PXQ^T)=(Q \otimes P)   \mathrm{vec(X)}$.

So it is sufficient to solve linear equation  $Bx=b$, 
where
$B=P \otimes Q+Q^T \otimes P^T$, $x=\mathrm{vec}(X)$, and $b=\mathrm{vec}(A)$.

Comment: Presumably you mean vectorization http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics), and $\mathrm{vec}(PQ)$ means $\mathrm{vec}(Q \otimes P)$.

Comment: $B$ should be $Q\otimes P + Q^T \otimes P^T$, without the $\operatorname{vec}$, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

If you are solving this numerically on a computer, you should use a variant of the Bartels-Stewart method; see for instance http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=146929 (Gardiner, Laub, Amato, Moler).

This costs $O(n^3)$ operations rather than $O(n^6)$ for the vectorization approach.

Comment: Why downvote? Did the vectorization approach was incorrect?

Comment: @Mahdi no, the idea works, it is just inefficient if the OP has practical solution in mind, and it seems to me that the algebra in your post is still incorrect. Please do not take the downvote as a personal thing.